# Adding alias functionality to a shell using Flex and Bison

Tags: shell, alias, bison, flex-lexer

I am building a shell using C, Flex, and Bison. Currently I have been able to create aliases, store them in a table with their respective commands, and recognize when a valid alias has been input. Now I am trying to implement processing aliases so that when a valid alias is input, the correct command executes. My thinking is that once a valid alias is found, I must somehow run the corresponding command through flex/bison again as though it were a totally separate, independent input

I am new to Flex and Bison so I am unsure of how to go about doing this. In general I am hoping for "You should check out X functions" rather than solid implementation, as I am using this project as a learning experience. Here are my flex and bison files, in case that is important : http://pastebin.com/t9QhkVUe

EDIT: I can also provide the main Shell code if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out flex's buffer stack functions. You could push a new buffer on to the buffer stack, set to the string value of the alias, and then pop the buffer stack in your `<<EOF>>` rule. See [Multiple Input Buffers](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html) in the flex manual, which has an example.

A token cannot start in a buffer and continue after the buffer is popped, but that's fine in this case because the result of the alias should not be allowed to "run into" the following text.

Don't forget to check for recursive alias expansion. To emulate a standard shell, you need to suppress alias expansion for any alias word currently being expanded. You could accomplish that by placing a "being_expanded" flag in the alias symbol table, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked out the topics you suggested , but I am still stuck, I am able to successfully set yytext equal to an alias's command upon a valid alias command being input. However, I guess I am still having trouble understanding how to go about replacing the user-input alias's name with the intended command that goes with it for Flex to give to Bison to make sense of. I've put my updated lex file here if you could be so kind as to take a look at it: (http://pastebin.com/cLAXzy6p)

Comment: @TheAlex: I don't think I can do a code review in a comment, but wrt pushing buffer states, you should definitely not be either trying to open a file (???) or setting yytext. (Or calling BEGIN(INITIAL), since you don't use start conditions.) What you need to do to push a string onto the buffer stack is:  `yypush_buffer_state(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER); yy_scan_string(alias_value);`. When you hit an `<<EOF>>`, `yypop_buffer_state();`. The first sequence is slightly non-obvious; it is required because yy_scan_string calls `yy_switch_to_buffer`.